# Getting an Error in angularjs 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying reddit application in angularjs2.

Getting an error:D:/Angular 2/SimpleReddit/src/app/component/Reddit/reddit.component.ts (9,13): Cannot find name 'Articles'

[image]

Here is my folder structure

.[image]

Reddit.component.ts

[image]

can any one help me on this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to import the class you want to use

```
import { Articles } from '../articles'; // Make sure the path is according to what you have in the project structure
```

Based on your project structure, seems you don't have a class called `Articles`.
A piece of advice, when naming classes instead of `Articles`, name it `Article`. It is better to use the singular form. So line 9 will look like:

```
articles: Article[];
```

So what you might need to do is to create a new file under your `Article` directory called `article.ts` and `export class Article { // your properties }` and include it as in the example above.

Comment: should i give complete path like import { Articles } from './app/component/Article/article.component';

Comment: `import { Articles } from '../Article/article.component';` should be enough if you're using it inside `Reddit.component.ts` file

Comment: If somehow your file `article.component.ts` contains a class `Articles` I recommend renaming it. Usually when you have a class that you use as a `model class`, you name it `model.ts` or `article.ts` in your case. It is not a component in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You have not imported the class Articles into your component, without it the typescript compiler cannot the type for this variable.

Add an import statement to import the class:

```
import { Articles } from './articles';
```

Adjust the path to the articles file accordingly

Comment: should i give complete path like                                                      import { Articles } from './app/component/Article/article.component';

Comment: The path should be relative to your current file location. So if the class  is in the article component file, within the Article folder the path becomes: '../Article/article.component'

Comment: Basic information about modules in in typescript, if you like to learn more about this topic. The doc is pretty good: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html